# Excel - how do I reference latest date cell in a column for a specific month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a bank balance Excel sheet with:

- Date in column A
- Debit/Credit in Column B
- Running balance in column C

On a separate sheet I want to have a 12 cells for months of the year that state what the balance in my account was on the last entry for that month that has a value in the balance column.

I have googled but can't find what I'm looking for.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have a look at Excel's database functions, particularly DGET or DMAX (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/dget-HP005209059.aspx). I've a feeling it's what you need. I'll see if I can elaborate later after work.

Comment: Hi Kaze, that's something I've never seen before and interesting, but don't have the necessary excel background to see how I would adapt it to my needs.  I would definitely appreciate your help. The number of rows (transactions) for any month varies, and as each month progresses the number of rows increases, so I can't see how to make the formulas in the 12 cells adapt, nor how to make the

Comment: Hi Kaze, that's something I've never seen before. I don't have the necessary excel background to see how I would adapt it to my needs.  I would definitely appreciate your help, thanks. The number of rows (transactions) for any month varies, and as each month progresses the number of rows increases, so I can't see how to make the formulas in the 12 cells adapt (maybe AA:CC ?).

Comment: This is what I'm thinking I want to be able to do:

End of January Balance = find max day value in column A from month January, then some kind of vlookup to return the Balance entry in the C column on the same row?

End of February Balance = find max day value in column A from month February, then some kind of vlookup to return the Balance entry in the C column on the same row?

Comment: Can you please add some example data? (Use 4 spaces to indent, to get fixed-width output.) Like: can a single date be present more than once? Are the dates really dates, or text? Could there be months without any data?

Comment: (And please delete your 1st comment: hover it with your mouse to see a delete icon appear. Thanks. Note the edit link underneath your question too: the question is actually the place for most if not all your comments. Please move them there.)

Comment: If Chris' answer solves this, then please "accept" that answer. And please see my comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is sorted in date accending order, you can use `VLOOKUP` for this

For conveniance name the account data range columns `A:C`, say `AccountData`.
On the summary sheet put the Date you want the balance for in one cell (say `A2`) and this formula in `B2`

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,AccountData,3,1)
```

To make getting the dates easy, use this formula in cell A3 and copy down (gets the last day of each month)

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+2,1)-1
```

Comment: Close, but what if some month(s) have no source data (yet)? And I think that the above requires that each date is listed in the source data only once (at most), which might not be true if there's a row for each bank transaction. (Also, the dates in the source data might actually be text, but that detail is lacking in the question too.)

Comment: @Arjan If no transactions exist for any given month then this still works: the balance returned is that of the previous month (which since no transactions exist is also the balance for the requested month).  Still works if more than one transaction exists for a month (on same or different dates in the month) as it returns the balance for the highest numbered day.  As I said the only constraint is that dates need to be sorted.  If dates are strings rather than serials thats a *bad* design and should be fixed.

Comment: Ah, of course: the balance of the previous month should suffice. Still then: if multiple rows exist for the same day, the above will fetch the first of those, right? (But as we're not sure that can even happen, despite the question referring to some bank statement, this is the simplest solution without any array formulas. Nice.)

Comment: @arjan, actualy no, vlookup with with `range_lookup` parameter set to 1 returns the index of the last value <= `Lookup_Value` which in this case is the final entry for the month, exactly what is required

Comment: Reading the documentation again I think you're right. The perfect answer then, too bad I cannot upvote twice ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply chris (and Arjan); It works perfectly, exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!!